# How to store credentials in the localStorages encrypted?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I have a small app which runs with JavaScript. In this app the user enters a Username and a Password. I would like to encrypt this username and password and then store it in the localStorage of the browser.

I know how to encrypt it, this is the easy part with a lib like Crypto-JS

My Question is: With which key should I encrypt the credentials so that the user does not have to enter it again?

Comment: "encrypt the credentials so that the user does not to enter it again" - that doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Don't do this. The way other sites & mobile apps do this is by making a second "session" key that you keep in a database serverside and expires after a longer time e.g. 2 weeks? which skips the logging in step ('cos the server doesn't need to keep the session in memory 24/7). But this key becomes basically a plaintext password that if shared/stolen could let anybody log in as you until it expires.

Comment: Your key, along with your decryption function will be available to everyone. This should not be done client-side, nor stored on client storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the Answer from Paul S. to finish this question:

> Don't do this. The way other sites & mobile apps do this is by making
>   a second "session" key that you keep in a database serverside and
>   expires after a longer time e.g. 2 weeks? which skips the logging in
>   step ('cos the server doesn't need to keep the session in memory
>   24/7). But this key becomes basically a plaintext password that if
>   shared/stolen could let anybody log in as you until it expires.